# Google Cloud Run server keeps restarting after 'Unhandled Exception:' with no details

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Dart server deployed onto Google Cloud Run. It works perfectly fine in my Dev environment. And works some of the time in Cloud Run. But too often it throws an error and restarts causing the request to fail.

See example logs below. Anyone know what might be causing the restart? Thanks!

> Server started at http://0.0.0.0:8080
>
> 2023-08-16 08:57:15.683 AEST Default STARTUP TCP probe succeeded after
> 1 attempt for container "lbapi-1" on port 8080.
>
> 2023-08-16 08:57:22.080 AEST Cloud Run v1 lbapi-00003-cid  {@type:
> type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, methodName: v1,
> resourceName: namespaces/lifeboat-5ac97/revisions/lbapi-00003-cid,
> response: {…}, serviceName: run.googleapis.com, status: {…}}
>
> 2023-08-16 08:57:27.819 AEST Cloud Run v1 lbapi  {@type:
> type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, methodName: v1,
> resourceName: namespaces/lifeboat-5ac97/services/lbapi, response: {…},
> serviceName: run.googleapis.com, status: {…}}
>
> 2023-08-16 08:57:35.034 AEST Unhandled exception:
>
> 2023-08-16 08:57:36.111 AEST PathNotFoundException: Directory listing
> failed, path =
> './dev/fd/11/proc/self/task/1/fd/10/1/fd/11/proc/thread-self/cwd/proc/1/task/1/fd/13/10/1/fd/14/proc/1/task/1/fd/15/1/task/1/fd/16/task/1/fd/17/fd/18/19/1/fd/20/fd/21/22/proc/1/task/1/fd/23/1/task/1/fd/25/root/proc/1/task/1/fd/26/proc/1/task/1/fd/27/1/task/1/fd/28/task/1/fd/29/1/fd/30/fd/31/32/13/14/proc/1/task/1/fd/33/1/fd/34/fd/35/36/proc/1/task/1/fd/37/1/task/1/fd/38/task/1/fd/39/1/fd/40/fd/43/task/8/fd/94'
> (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
>
> 2023-08-16 08:57:37.863 AEST Container called exit(255).
>
> 2023-08-16 08:57:38.085 AEST Starting recharge..